# Initializing a pair of variables- what does the 1 mean?

Tags: python

I'm trying to fundamentally understand while loops but don't understand assigning multiple variables on a single line of code.

total, x = 0, 1

What does the 1 mean? Where does the 1 belong? Plz help

Comment: try `print(total, x)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
total, x = 0, 1
```

it means :

```
total = 0
```

and

```
x = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are basically assigning two variables simultaneously.

```
cat, dog = 'meow', 'woof'
```

is the same as:

```
cat = 'meow'
dog = 'woof'
```

You can use this method when you have a function that needs to return multiple variables.

```
def my_func(text):
  return text, text.upper()

(original, edited) = my_func('hello')

print(original)
print(edited)
>>> hello
>>> HELLO
```